# What is the difference between a bacterial artificial chromosome (BAC) and a plasmid?

Tags: genetics, bacteriology, plasmids

Is it just that a BAC is generally larger and artificially constructed? Or are there any other differences?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacterial_artificial_chromosome, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BACs are a special kind of plasmid, based on *E. coli*'s F-plasmid:

> The BAC is based on a plasmid in *Escherichia coli* that is termed the F (for fertility) plasmid. The F plasmid (or F factor) contains information that makes possible the process called conjugation . In conjugation, two *Escherichia coli* bacteria can physically connect and an exchange of DNA can occur.
>
> A BAC contains the conjugation promoting genetic information as well as stretch of DNA that is destined for incorporation into the bacterium.

[Source](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Bacterial_Artificial_Chromosome_(BAC).aspx)

It isn't necessarily larger than a plasmid.